# Align footer to the bottom of printed HTML page?

Tags: printing, media-queries, footer, vertical-alignment, sticky-footer

I have a standard website, and when printed (for PDF-making purposes on Safari OS X), I'd like the footer to align to the bottom of whatever printed page it is on — i.e. the last page of the document.

Like this:

[image: Print-footer-align-to-bottom]

Is that possible?

I have used a media query (`@media print { }`) for all other print stylesheet details (excluded for simplicity).

[Demo code is here](http://jsbin.com/inokup/1/edit); for the `screen` page itself, here is the HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <p>A bunch of example stuff inside here...</p>
</div>
```

Which is situated with absolute positioning:

```
#footer {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176770/footer-on-last-printed-page

Comment: @ChrisF, the solution to that question didn't work — it puts it on the first page. This question is about putting it on the bottom of the last page.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an old one but the answer is surely to use the `@page:last` selector, but you have to alter the CSS for the footer as well.

```
#footer { position: static; }

@page:last {
    @bottom-center { content:element(footer) }
}
```

Comment: i don't think @page:last is a existent directive