# How to assign a CSS page counter to a variable?

Tags: css, sass

I want to use the value generated by `counter(pages)` in order to do something specific on the last page of a printed web document using an `@page` rule.

Using `counter(pages)` is working fine for me in an at-page context:

```css
    @page {
      @top-right {
        content: counter(pages);
      }
    }
```

Addressing a specific page also works fine:

```css
    @page: nth(69) {
      @top-right {
        content: normal;
      }
    }
```

What I want is to pass the total page count to `nth()`, like so:

```css
    @page: nth(#{counter(pages)}) {
      @top-right {
        content: normal;
      }
    }
```

Without success.

I've tried using a SASS variable:

```css
    $pagecount: 69; // this works
    $pagecount: '69'; // even this works
    $pagecount: #{counter(pages)}; // but this doesn't
    $pagecount: counter(pages); // nor does this
    ...
    @page: nth(#{$pagecount}) {...}
    ...
```

When I try to use the dynamic value my code always compiles to

```css
    @page :nth(counter(pages)) {}
```

which of course does nothing.
Is it possible to get the total page count into `nth()`?

Comment: .page:last-child { color: red }? In css you do not know anything about html. So you can't get the actual count of elements.

Comment: Thank you but I think this won't let me do what I want – I want to do something specific to the page margins on the last page using an [@page rule](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-page-rule). I've edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041039/4306572 maybe this would be helpful

Comment: Wow, that's looking very promising although my setup (using Prince for creating a pdf) seems unable to parse named pages. Will try if I can get it to work with weasyprint. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this works great, also with Prince. Thanks again, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [3rdthemagical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4306572/3rdthemagical), an answer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041039/11502557) achieves what I want, not by using `counter(pages)` but instead by using [named pages](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#using-named-pages) on an element that is positioned on the last page of the document.