# Print Label at bottom of last page in Html

Tags: html, css, print-preview

I want to print the highlighted content (see screenshot) at the bottom of the last page in my HTML report. When I set `position:fixed;`, it's coming on each page.

[image: Buyer Confirmation]

```css
.BuyerSign {
        height: 40px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        width: 28%;
        padding-left: 25px;
        text-align: right;
        bottom:0px !important;
        /*bottom: 0px !important;*/
        /*bottom:-200px !important;
        position:relative !important;*/
    }
```

```html
  <div class="BuyerSign" style="">
                            <label style="border-top:1px solid #000;text-align:center;">
                                Buyer Confirmation
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42136333/css-paged-media-last-page-selector

Answer (score 0):

u should set the container div to relative:

```css
.BuyerSign {
        position:relative;
        bottom:0px;
        height: 40px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        width: 28%;
        padding-left: 25px;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="BuyerSign" style="">
                            <label style="border-top:1px solid #000;text-align:center;">
                                Buyer Confirmation
                            </label>
                        </div>
```